# Get the count of messages in-memory message store in wso2 esb

Tags: java, xml, wso2, wso2-esb

How to get the count of messages in-memory message store in WSO2 ESB?
I want to get the count in XML configuration, like to be used in proxy service or sequence or message processor etc.
I want it to be used in XML.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Any efforts given to clear the question by your self?

Comment: I don't know how to get the count from In-memory store, I am only able to read the message from message store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by pushing the message to db and get as per the count required as in this answer of me [take a look at my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138913/how-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-from-database-using-wso2-esb/31154782)

Answer (score 1):

You can use script mediator with this code:

```
var msg_store = mc.getConfiguration().getMessageStore('YourMessageStoreName')
var log = mc.getServiceLog()
log.info("Current size of Message Store "+msg_store.size())
```