# How to retrieve multiple rows from database using WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I want to retrieve multiple rows in a db using wso2 esb. Using dblookup mediator I am able to retreive only one row. It is suggested to use WSO2 DSS can you please help me with using DSS to retrieve multiple rows in ESB completely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working without DSS.

just write a script mediator to call dblookup or dbreport mediator as many times as how many rows required.

```
var a=mc.getSequence('gett');
        a.getList().get(0).mediate(mc);
        a.getList().get(1).mediate(mc);
        a.getList().get(2).mediate(mc);
```

here 'gett' is my sequence and it has 3 child so i'm call all three.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use DSS (which is our case), then you might try the custom mediator that can be found here.

https://github.com/mephist/wso2-esb-dbselect

Answer (score 0):

Data Service server is used to expose your data(base) ,with sql ,as an available xml/restful web services . You could then call the data service through its endpoint from your ESB proxy service, receiving your result set(any # rows), so it is suited to your requirement.

Perhaps you should try to experiment with it first and post any issues you arrive at.